# laravel mkdir() Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel-5

I try the following method to create a folder with it's subdirectorys if it does not already exists:

```
public function createFolderIfNotExist($path){
    //Check if the folder already exists
    if(!File::Exists($path)){
        //make folder with $path generate recursive with right 0775
        File::makeDirectory($path, 0775 , true);
    }
}
```

When running localy it works fine (xampp), when pushed to the server it returns

> permission denied

First lines of the error

> in Filesystem.php line 337
>
> at HandleExceptions->handleError('2',
>   'mkdir(): Permission denied',
>   '/var/www/****/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php',
>   '337', array('path' =>
>   '/var/www/****/public/images\product\206', 'mode' =>
>   '509', 'recursive' => true, 'force' => false))
>
> at
>   mkdir('/var/www/****/public/images\product\206', '509',
>   true) in Filesystem.php line 337
>
> at
>   Filesystem->makeDirectory('/var/www/****/public/images\product\206',
>   '509', true) in Facade.php line 216
>
> at
>   Facade::__callStatic('makeDirectory',
>   array('/var/www/****/public/images\product\206', '509',
>   true)) in ProductController.php line 452

The error message makes it look like im trying to set the permissions to 509

The path that I pass is:

```
$pathThumb = public_path('images\product\\'.$product->id.'\thumb');
```

When checking the permisson on the server it says 775 for the public folder.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you are running *nix on the server. Did you check if your Selinux disabled?

Also, you have to set directory ownership to the group or user that your apache/nginx runs on.  you have to run  

 chgrp apache product -Rf 

if you are running apache: check in your httpd.conf what user and group your server runs. (give that user permission).

Its very likely that you use different user for FTP to upload files and different user for webserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unix user that the php server runs under does not have permission to access the parent directory at `$path`.

Googling `"permission denied" makeDirectory` [shows the same](https://www.google.com/?q=%22permission%20denied%22%20makeDirectory).

The problem is outside of PHP, so you need to determine how to [make the folder writeable like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119358/create-file-in-folder-permission-denied), or make the files in a directory that is writable to the php server process user.  This should involve your sysadmin/devops person.

Comment: From the `googling results`, just **ignore** the advice `change to 777` and the comments `777 works like a charm`

Comment: One can expose themselves and their company to significant security risk by following @Pathros `777` advice — e.g. spammers could use one's server as a spam or malware relay, causing the company domain to be blacklisted, resulting in an inability to market the product online.